# Pagination and JOIN with Laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

I'm having a strange behavior (due to my fault I guess) while trying to paginate some results after a JOIN using Eloquent ORM.

This is the code that causes Laravel to return a blank (no errors are shown) 500 error page:

```
return Entry::join('articles', 'entries.id', '=', 'articles.entryID')
        ->orderBy('articles.created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(15, array('articles.*'));
```

If I swap `paginate(...)` with `get(...)` the page is correctly shown and data is returned.

**Edit**:

This is how I create both the `articles` and `entries` tables:

```
// Entries
Schema::create('entries', function($table) {

    $table->string('app', 20);
    $table->bigInteger('comments');
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('owner', 255)
          ->foreign('owner')
          ->references('username')
          ->on('users');
    $table->dateTime('timestamp');
    $table->bigInteger('views');
    $table->bigInteger('votes');
    $table->dateTime('created_at');
    $table->dateTime('deleted_at');
    $table->dateTime('updated_at');
});


// Articles
Schema::create('articles', function($table) {

    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('author')
          ->foreign('author')
          ->references('username')
          ->on('users');
    $table->text('content');
    $table->bigInteger('entryID')
          ->foreign('entryID')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('entries');
    $table->string('status', 20);
    $table->string('summary', 1000);
    $table->string('title', 255);
    $table->dateTime('created_at');
    $table->dateTime('deleted_at');
    $table->dateTime('updated_at');
});
```

**Edit 2**:

This is what I get in `laravel.log`:

```
[2014-08-26 19:59:54] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 129499136 bytes)' in /usr/share/nginx/html/webname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:605
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

**Edit 3**:

I've disabled the memory limit and the log with

```
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

but the whole system freezes for about 1 minute like it starts a loop or something.

**Edit 4**:

I've added my issue here too: http://help.laravel.io/00f4a0793d2291d73214e0b6f56320b84caaf51d

**Edit 5**:

It looks like there's something wrong with my system or it's a bug in Laravel.

I have also tried to manually create the paginator:

```
$entries = Entry::join('articles', 'entries.id', '=', 'articles.entryID')
    ->orderBy('entries.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();    // Data is correctly retrieved from the DB

$paginator = Paginator::make($entries->toArray(), self::count());
dd($paginator);
die();
```

The page is still not rendered and I keep receiving the error: `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`

Comment: how you solved this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found out that the problem was caused by:

`dd($pagination)`

Looks like I cannot dump the paginator object returned by the function.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the paginate method for Eloquent; theoretically, it should work.  Eloquent is fantastic, but personally, I've found that Fluent is better for queries with `join()`s

```
return DB::table('entries')
        ->join('articles', 'entries.id', '=', 'articles.entryID')
        ->orderBy('articles.created_at', 'desc')
        ->select('articles.*')
        ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried too, but I still get an empty blank page with 500 error status :S

Comment: Seeing as `get()` works for you, i think it is the `articles.*`.  what happens when you dot use the wildcard just for debugging purposes?  select('`articles.entryID`').  Or, just remove the `select()` all together.

Comment: If I remove the wildcard I get the error page, but whenever I try to use `select('articles.entryID')` I still get the blank page with no errors at all. Now, could it be a DB problem?

Comment: It could be.  Can you post your 2 tables `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: The only thing i can think of is: since paginator aggregates using the id field, your `$table->bigIncrements('id');` could be causing a problem.  This is a supported method, however, i have never had any problems using the traditional `$table->increments('id');`  Also, using Laravel naming conventions, `ectryID` should be `entry_id`.  That shouldn't make a difference, the way you are structuring the query, but just a thought.  Do you have anything pertaining tot his in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: Also, be sure your `id` column has an index of `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: That helps!  Seems to be a common problem due to Laravel keeping a persistent query log... Try it with disabling your query log  `DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();`.  If that doesn't help, also try removing your memory limit to debug `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

Comment: I've removed the memory limit and disabled the query log but the whole system freezes for about 1 minute.